# INSERT INTO ...ERROR NOT inserting

Tags: php, mysql

Can Anyone Tell me Why its not inserting into Database  ?

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET["job"]) && $_GET["job"] == "positive" && !empty($_GET["positive"]))
 {
          $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts (positive) values( '1')") or die ("uploading error! Try diffrent base or contact dev!");
 }

?>


<script>
 function positive(account)
 {
  top.document.location.href = "myaccounts.php?job=positive&positive="+account;
 }
</script>
<td class="formstyle"><div align="center" style="padding:5px;">
<img src="" width="35" height="35" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="if(confirm(\'Confirm Positive Feedback ?\')) positive(\''.$row["account_id"].'\');" /></div>
</td>
```

im trying to add with onclick feature the script its on there too.... please any help im stucked here like 12h

Comment: In what way does this fail?  Is the JavaScript code executed?  Does the browser location successfully change?  Does the PHP code execute?  What is the response from the server?  What specifically happens here?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending a non-empty `account` parameter?

Comment: You're not putting `$_GET["positive"]` into the DB, you're always putting `1`.

Comment: The browser give me respons with this link : 

myaccounts.php?job=positive&positive="ACCOUNT ID"  yes the javascript code its executing but its not inserting into database when i check ...

Comment: You've been at this for 12 hours...  have you considered returning the error message reported by MySQL? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php  Does your PHP script establish a connection to MySQL before the  attempt to execute a query? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php  There's some pretty rudiementary debugging steps we'd expect, with no evidence of any those steps.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Come one man im not starter for sure i have made the connection...

Comment: Yes barmar im trying to insert number 1 into database

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding `Mysql_error()` at end of `DIE()` that will give you more info on error.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts SET positive=\"".'1'."\"") or die ("uploading error! Try diffrent base or contact dev! ".mysql_error());
```

A way to not show `mysql_error();` so people done see it.

EX:

```
function errorsignup($error,$details,$message)
{
    if($message == "")
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO er SET name=\"".$error."\",details=\"".$details."\"") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
    else
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO er SET name=\"".$error."\",details=\"".$details."\"") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
        return $message;
    }
}
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
function standarderror()
{
    return "OH NO... An Error Has Occured<br />We Were Not Expecting This<br />An Error Message With Details Has Been Sent To Web Admin.<br /> You May Try One Of The Following<ul><li>Try Again</li><li>Or Return To Home Page Then Try Again</li><li>Wait 24 Hours And Try Again</li><li>If Error Persists Then Please Just Wait 24 Hours.</li></ul><br />Thanks For Your Support: Web Master / Administrator - Double J Computers";
}
```

now we add the error message after every `mysql_query();`

```
die(errorsignup('Error In Your Area: - SQL UPDATE edit - '.date('m-d-y').' - '.getRealIpAddr(),'SQL ERROR: '.mysql_error(),standarderror())); // this returns the standard error function so people have a few instructions to try again.
//this also records the area like what page and what sql edit or update or w/e and the full error
```

Comment: Still not working ... can u please check the ISSET if i have maked an mistake

Comment: Its like the asset its not executing i have removed now the asset its same thing just refreshing and the javascript puts the code into the browswer

Comment: the mysql_error(); Helps Alot I have also Edited The Answer To Set Mysql_ERROR into a database so you can check errors instead of showing them externally.

Comment: Hey do u know now how can i add something just into the POSITIVE Row into to an existing data !

Comment: This habit of using `...\"".$x."\"...` is really problematic and suggests you don't fully understand how [PHP can interpolate strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: mysql like to have escaped `"` in there line so `\"` escapes and you use a variable like `$data` so `("INSERT INTO database SET name=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."\" WHERE id=".$id); ` how is this wrong?